# What does the phrase "Modern industry has established the world market, for which the discovery of America paved the way" mean?

Tags: meaning

I understand each separate word but the meaning of the whole phrase is obscure to me. I particularly do not understand what "for which" is used for.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The quote about which (see later) you note, "I particularly do not understand what "for which" is used for.":

> Modern industry has established the world market, for which the discovery of America paved the way.

In this context, *for which* connects the three items:

- the world market (the beneficiary - it was *for* the world market; *which* = the market);
- the discovery of America (the main action - what caused the 'benefit' to the beneficiary); and
- paved the way (the benefit to the beneficiary).

**Putting this together**, the *discovery of America* was what *paved the way* for the *world market*.

As a similar example, consider "*about which*" in the opening sentence of this answer: *you* made the *note* about the *quote*.